# Is $f(x)=|x|(x-\sin x)$ bijective

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x)=|x|\left(x-\sin x\right)$. Is $f$ bijective.

**My Attempt:**

To prove whether $f$ is bijective we need to prove that $f$ is both one-one(injective) and onto(surjective).

Since $f$ is odd and continuous it will clearly extend from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ so $f$ can be regarded as onto. But I am not able to get a rigorous proof for this or is my argument sufficient.

Also to prove that $f$ is one-one let us assume that $f$ is many-one.

So, there would exist $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R^+}$ such that $x_1\neq x_2$ but $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$

$|x_1|\left(x_1-\sin x_1\right)=|x_2|\left(x_2-\sin x_2\right)$

$x_1^2-x_2^2=x_1\sin x_1-x_2\sin x_2$

$(x_1+x_2)(x_1-x_2)=(x_1-x_2)\sin x_1+x_2(\sin x_1-\sin x_2)$

$x_1+x_2=\sin x_1+x_2\left(\frac{\sin x_1-\sin x_2}{x_1-x_2}\right)$

$x_1+x_2=\sin x_1+x_2\cos\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)\frac{\sin(\frac{x_1-x_2}{2})}{\frac{x_1-x_2}{2}}<x_1+x_2$

which is a contradiction. So $f$ is one-one. Is this method correct.

I was wondering that if I prove $f'(x)>0 \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ then it could be easily proved that since $f$ is strictly increasing so $f$ is one-one.

But I am not able to justify $f'(x)>0 \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I don't see how you got from the first indented line (after the sentence starting "So, there would...") to the second indented line. Please fill in *all* the steps of your chain of equalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that your function is odd. Therefore since it is positive for $x>0$ we cn establish it is one-to-one by showing it is increasing for positive $x.$ For these $x$ you function is $g(x)=x^2-x \sin x.$ The derivative of $g(x)$ can be written as
$$ x(2-\cos x) - \sin x.$$
Now for positive $x$ we have $(2-\cos x) \ge 1$ so that the first term above is $\ge x.$ Now use that for positive $x$ we have $x > \sin x$ to conclude that $g'(x)>0$ which shows your function is indeed strictly increasing for positive $x$ as claimed, therefore one-to one. Together with your original function being odd, it is thus a bijection. [Your approach to showing surjective only needs the added fact that it takes on arbitrarily large values.]

**Added later:** User @RamanujanXXV has noted a shorter proof, Namely each of the functions $u(x)=x,\ v(x)=x-\sin x$ is strictly increasing on the positive reals, so their product is also.

Comment: Aliter for derivative is observing that both $x$ and $x-\sin x$ are increasing thus, their product will also be increasing.

Comment: @RamanujanXXV Yes indeed, and that would give a much shorter proof than my answer does. [If you put that as an answer I'd upvote it.]

Comment: I would have loved to answer it but unfortunately I am travelling ,anyways it would also be great if you include this aliter in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\arctan(x)$ is odd and continuous but doesn't extend from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. You need to do more to prove that the function is surjective.